Debian on quad boot system only finds Windows 10 (which finds Win XP, which finds Win 98)
So, I managed to get my 17 years old Intel Core2 Quad running with Windows 98, XP, 10 and Debian 12 on top.
I first installed Windows 98, then Windows XP. This lead to an XP boot menu which offered me XP or 98. Then I installed Windows 10 which lead to a boot menu which offered me Windows 10 or "other version of Windows". If I select "other version", I get the XP boot loader.
Then I installed Debian on the fourth and last primary partition (no UEFI) which installed Grub2 and offers me the entries Debian and "Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)". Selecting "Windows 10" in Grub2 gets me the Win10 boot loader etc.
sda1, however, is Win98, so Win10 must have installed itself there. But where did Grub2 install itself to, then?
What I actually wanted to achieve is to have all four entries in Grub2. What can I do to achieve that? The os-prober only finds Win10.
I can see and mount all Windows partitions without issues.

There's really no need for the downvote

Initially, the system had a classic Windows 9x MBR boot code, and a DOS-style FAT32 boot code in the Partition Boot Record (PBR) of the Windows 98 partition (sda1).
After adding XP, it must have replaced the Windows 9x MBR with a Windows 2000/XP/2003-style MBR boot code, as the XP boot manager (NTLDR) can do the job of the Windows 9x MBR when that OS is selected in the XP boot menu. The XP's primary partition (sda2 I guess) would also have had a PBR of appropriate type installed to it (either a FAT32 NT5.0 type or a NTFS type).
Likewise, after adding Windows 10 (to sda3?), the MBR code was again replaced by a Windows 7+-style MBR boot code, which invokes the Windows 10 boot manager (bootmgr).
But Windows Vista and newer versions will want to put their boot manager to a partition that is different from the main system partition. I guess you'll find a file named bootmgr in the root directory of sda1; in Windows, it will probably have hidden/system/read-only attributes, so it will normally be invisible. Because of this, Windows 10 may also have overwritten the PBR of sda1 with a "NT6.0" style FAT32 partition boot record.
And finally, installing Debian 12 replaced the MBR code yet again with GRUB. Parts of GRUB will also be contained in the gap between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition, which is normally just unused space to satisfy partition alignment requirements.
The Windows tests of os-prober seem to require the partitions to be mounted: if your Windows partitions were not mounted when you ran os-prober, that might be the reason they got ignored.
The BIOS version of GRUB starts Microsoft operating systems by chainloading their PBR. So there should be no problem starting XP from sda2 and Windows 10 from sda1. You might want to add something like this to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and run sudo update-grub if running os-prober with the Windows partitions mounted doesn't work out:
menuentry 'Windows 10/Windows Boot Manager (on sda3+sda1)' {
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        chainloader +1
}

menuentry 'Windows XP/NTLDR (on sda2)' {
        insmod ntfs                     # or insmod fat, as appropriate
        set root='hd0,msdos2'
        chainloader +1
}

Unfortunately, since Windows 9x's PBR is no longer in the first block of the sda1 partition, it cannot be booted quite like that any more.
But I think I remember how NTLDR boots older versions of Windows: it stores a copy of the other operating system's PBR on the disk the NTLDR itself is located on, using a name like bootsect.dos or bootsect.w98. You should see the name of the file if you read the BOOT.INI file of Windows XP on sda2.
Knowing that, you might want to copy the bootsect.* file from the root directory of sda2 to sda1, just to safeguard it in case you ever decide to get rid of Windows XP (and to generally minimize interdependencies between the different OS partitions). Then you could add a GRUB menu entry like this:
menuentry 'Windows 98 (on sda1)' {
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        chainloader /bootsect.w98  # or bootsect.dos as the case may be
}

This should load the preserved copy of the Windows 9x PBR from the copied file, allowing Windows 98 to boot directly from GRUB.
Unfortunately you cannot completely separate the partitions of Windows 98 and Windows 10 without doing major transplantation surgery to the Windows 10 bootloader, which is off topic here at Unix&Linux StackExchange. (And since Windows 10 claims to have "self-healing" features, it might just add it back to sda1 on its own anyway.)

From 101 to 101k: thanks a lot! I'll look into it later. But you got the sda's right.

I posted a follow-up on SuperUser.SE: https://superuser.com/questions/1850295/how-to-get-3-windows-partitions-and-1-linux-partition-into-grub2

Actually, i386-pc grub also has ntldr that can be used too execute either /ntldr or /bootmgr directly.
